# What happens at the moment I no longer meet multiclass prerequisites during gameplay?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, ability-scores

Suppose I've got a multiclass fighter/cleric with both wisdom and strength of 16. Nice.

I fall victim to a shadow's ***strength drain*** attack. Not nice. I roll a 4 and lose 4 points of strength.

Uh-oh.

I no longer meet the prerequisite for my multiclass. Do I lose my fighter class features until after my next rest, when that strength comes back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when it's time to level up and I no longer meet a multiclass prerequisite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105987/what-happens-when-its-time-to-level-up-and-i-no-longer-meet-a-multiclass-prereq)

Comment: Voting to close this one. The linked question's answers can answer this one too. Actually they are pretty much the same.

Comment: @Mindwin depending on which way the answer(s) go I could see them being duplicates, or being quite distinct. Which we won't know until they've ripened a bit, methinks. In any case, I won't vote either way and will let the answering and voting out. (Though if anything, I'd think the duplicate would flow from that to this, not the other way around.)

Comment: While they could certainly be merged, the questions are distinct enough as is, one asking what happens immediately, the other asking specifically if advancement is possible. Related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 16):

### No, you don't lose your current features

> To **qualify** for a new class, you must meet the ability score prerequisites ...

You already qualified ***at the time*** you picked the additional class (which, according to the above quote, is the only thing that matters by RAW in the Player's Handbook ) and now you are of that class forevermore.