# What happens when it's time to level up and I no longer meet a multiclass prerequisite?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, ability-scores

Suppose I'm playing a multiclass fighter/druid (because [that's how I Range](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=39585180#39585180)). I've got both Wisdom and Dexterity above 13, but Strength's only 10.

I annoy an efreet, who uses *wish*es to reduce both my Wisdom and Dexterity to 12. (Because my GM's a lawyer and knows that I care about the rules, and that this will tie me into knots.)

It's time to level up, and I don't meet the prerequisite for either of my classes. Probably don't meet the prereq for *any* third class, since I was so focused on Wisdom and Dexterity! Am I stuck until I otherwise raise a stat?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

RAW: it appears that this would not matter.

Page 163 of the PHB (emphasis mine):

> **To qualify for a new class**, you must meet the ability score prerequisites for both your current class and your new one, as shown
>   in the Multiclassing Prerequisites table.

In your scenario you just would not be able to qualify for any new classes. Nothing in the rules that I have ever seen indicates that you must have a specific ability score to continue levelling. If they intended that to be a limitation they would likely have stated it explicitly.

So it would appear, by that wording, that you just would not be able to qualify for additional multiclassing to any additional classes.

Answer (score 15):

### You can probably continue to level.

The rules aren't entirely clear, but a drastically strict reading of the text would probably support your ability to continue to gain levels. The Prerequisite section in Multiclassing (PHB p.163) says:

> To qualify for a new class, you must meet the ability score
>   prerequisites for both your current class and your new one.

It says nothing about continuing to gain levels in a class you already have levels in, only qualifying for a *new* class. Presumably a case could be made that it takes exceptional ability to change to a brand new set of skills and abilities, but once already on that path, continuing is not as difficult.

Comment: I think your reasoning is backed up by the fact that you could roll a Wizard with a 10 Intelligence if you so desired.  Such a Wizard could reach level 20 with no issues by RAW.  By RAW you could never join a new class though, even though your 18 Strength might seem to qualify you as a Fighter.  Even though it seems a little odd, I think that this rule is necessary to prevent people from sneaking into a multiclass through the backdoor, i.e., starting in the class you have a low stat in and then adding your high stat class.